# Regular expression to match specific pattern

Tags: c#, regex

Please help me correct this regular expression in C# to match/validate only when the following is true:

- Always starts with `da/`
- At least one single character after `da/`
- Only non capitals are allowed, range from a-z (both included)
- digits 0-9 allowed
- dashes are allowed (-)

This is what I have, but it's not working:

```
/^da/+[a-z0-9+-]+$/
```

Example of accepted string that will validate the regular expression:

```
da/this-will-validate-correct-1
```

Comment: *but not working* - how exactly doesn't it work? Please provide sample input and expected output. Most probably you just need `^da/[a-z0-9+-]+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex allows 1 or more `/` after `da` and the `+` inside the character class allowed `+` symbols.

Judging by the requirements, you just need

```
^da/[a-z0-9-]+$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5eda%2f%5ba-z0-9-%5d%2b%24&i=da%2fthis-will-validate-correct-1)

The `+` after the character class `[a-z0-9+-]` requires at least 1 character after `da/`.

```
Regex.IsMatch("da/this-will-validate-correct-1", @"^da/[a-z0-9-]+$")
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/YpHsCJ)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `da/` - a literal string of characters `da/`
- `[a-z0-9-]+` - 1 or more characters from `a-z` and `0-9` ranges or a `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `^da/[a-z0-9\-]+$`